# How do I repeat words several times in Python?

Tags: python, ascii, caesar-cipher

I'm wanting to create a string that will, If Word 1 was `CHEESE` and Word 2 = `HAM`, create a string looking something like this...

`CHEESEHAMCHEESEHAMCHEESEHAMCHEESEHAM` etc...

I then want the ASCII values of each character to  be taken and be used in a Caesar cipher program.

Thanks in advance, I'm not too experienced with Python.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: `'HAM'.join(['CHESSE']*4)`

Comment: Not too much yet, I've done the first part of my work in which I had to provide a number that would then be added to the ASCII value of each value in the message in order to get an alternative letter for the cipher. Any chance you could help get me started?

Comment: Look for a python tutorial over the internet?

Comment: Cheers Dain, but when I run the program nothing happens... It's been a while since I did some coding 0_0

Comment: And ideally I'm wanting to get this done pretty quickly, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate two strings `s1` and `s2`, you use the `+` operator:

```
s = s1 + s2
```

To repeat a string `s` `n` (integer number) times, you use the `*` operator:

```
ss = s * n
```

To get a list of integers representing each character of a string `ss`, you can use the built-in `ord()` method in a list comprehension:

```
l = [ord(c) for c in ss]
```

So a full program using two strings and the number of repetitions (here hard-coded as constants), and with the snippets above compressed into one line, would look like this:

```py
s1 = "CHEESE"
s2 = "HAM"
n = 5

l = [ord(c) for c in (s1+s2)*n]
print (l)
```

Comment: You're the first one on [SO] who calls me "master"... :D

Comment: As this answer seems to have helped you and solved your problem, please accept it (click the grey tick on the left of it). Thanks! Also make sure to have read the [tour] page, where you learn the most important things about how this site works in less than two minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this.

```
wordOne="cheese"
wordTwo="ham"
i=0
n=5
while i<n:
    print("wordOne", end="")
    print("wordTwo", end="")
    i+=1
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll try it out :)

Comment: You know that you're reinventing the wheel? (`i=0; while i<n: i+=1` instead of `for i in range(n):`) Also, list comprehensions are faster than ordinary loops.

Comment: I don't know that they are faster than while loops. thank you for comment. I'm also new on python.